# How to escape special chars powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using the code below to send some keys to automate some process in my company.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

$wshell.SendKeys("here comes my string");
```

The problem is that the string that gets sent must be sanitazed to escape some special chars as described [here](http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-sendkeys.html).

For example: `{, [, +, ~` all those symbols must be escaped like `{{}, {[}, {+}, {~}`

So I am wondering: is there any easy/clean way to do a replace in the string? I dont want to use tons of `string.replace("{","{{}");`  `string.replace("[","{[}")`

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression (RegEx for short) to do this. RegEx is used for pattern matching, and works great for what you need. Ironicly you will need to escape the characters for RegEx before defining the RegEx pattern, so we'll make an array of the special characters, escape them, join them all with `|` (which indicates `OR`), and then replace on that with the `-replace` operator.

```
$SendKeysSpecialChars = '{','}','[',']','~','+','^','%'
$ToEscape = ($SendKeysSpecialChars|%{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
"I need to escape [ and } but not # or !, but I do need to for %" -replace "($ToEscape)",'{$1}'
```

That produces:

```
I need to escape {[} and {}} but not # or !, but I do need to for {%}
```

Just put the first two near the beginning of the script, then use the replace as needed. Or make a function that you can call that'll take care of the replace and the SendKeys call for you.

Comment: PERFECTLY! That's exactly what I need! :) :) Would you mind telling me how did you use Escape($_) ?

Comment: I used `[regex]::Escape()` to escape the strings for the regex match, so that the regex match would not have issues with RegEx specific reserved characters (such as `[`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Here Strings**.

Note: *Here Strings* were designed for multi-line strings, but you can still use them to escape expression characters.

As stated on [***this***](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) website.

> A here string is a single-quoted or double-quoted string which can
> span multiple lines. Expressions in single-quoted strings are not
> evaluated.
>
> All the lines in a here-string are interpreted as strings,
> even though they are not enclosed in quotation marks.

Example:

---

> To declare a here string you have to use a new-line for the text
> itself, Powershell syntax.

```
$string = @'
{ [ + ~ ! £ $ % ^ & ( ) _ - # ~ @ '' "" 
'@
```

Output: `{ [ + ~ ! £ $ % ^ & ( ) _ - # ~ @ '' ""`

Comment: Good intention, but wrong context. The OP needs to escape characters in reference to the SendKeys module, as shown in their link, and implied in their code.

Comment: Oh thank you! Completely thought of the wrong Thing.

Comment: Thanks anyway my friend but that's not what I am looking for. I cant believe how hard this is cause this should be in the core of powershell, allow user to escape chars... PHP, ASP.. all have very easy ways to do that.